# LINQ2SQL Updating Database but only when I view in SQL Server

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a really odd problem.

I have 3 tables.

1. Positions
2. PositionAttachments
3. Attachments

I won't bore you with the keys and foreign keys as that should be kinda evident.

If I add a **new** position, attachment and positionattachment all's well.

If I add a new attachment to an existing Position record i get the following.

1. Positions table is updated and I can see changes on screen
2. Attachment table has new record
3. PositionAttachments table has new record
4. New Attachment does not appear on screen within my application
5. Close application, recompile and re run and I have the same as 4
6. View ANY table through SQL server and I get kicked out of my session and once I log back in I see the records on screen.

At no point is there an error being generated.

Update record code;

```
    public void AddAttachmentToPosition(PositionsAvailable positionModel, Attachment attachment)
    {
        //attachment.id = Guid.NewGuid();
        dc.Attachments.InsertOnSubmit(attachment);

        PositionAttachment positionAttachment = new PositionAttachment();
        positionAttachment.PositionId = positionModel.PositionId;
        positionAttachment.AttachmentId = attachment.id;
        //positionAttachment.id = Guid.NewGuid();

        dc.PositionAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(positionAttachment);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

**Edit**

I have looked at the log produced by the Data context and I get this for the PositionAttachments insert.  It looks essentially the same for the Attachments table.

```
DECLARE @output TABLE([id] UniqueIdentifier)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PositionAttachments]([PositionId], [AttachmentId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] INTO @output
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
SELECT [id] FROM @output
-- @p0: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [92a3627d-ad01-466e-a315-423c851efc5d]
-- @p1: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [db566728-a313-40c7-af82-0a2f147234eb]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.5420
```

To my mind, this looks pretty normal.  And besides, the same code works when I am adding a new Position just not when I am adding attachments to an existing position.

Comment: what is your strategy concerning lifetime of the DC?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, it'd be nice if you mentioned why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, what if you try:

```
    PositionAttachment positionAttachment = new PositionAttachment(); 
    positionAttachment.Position = positionModel; 
    positionAttachment.Attachmen = attachment;
```

Although I think the DC should also pick up the ID's properly

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work either.  This is something I've done a million times so I just can't figure out why this wont work

Comment: Actually this, with a couple of mods, is working a little bit.  Thanks.  I think the rest should now be fairly easy.

Comment: Rather than try to add the items into two tables i simply used the model to do it.  I get the PositionAvailable record and create a PositionAttachment object and then add the attachment to it and use thisPos.PositionAttachments.add(positionattachment).  Simple but for some reason i was missing it until i saw your answer